# Drawing mulitple MKpolygons in a single

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpolygon

I'm using a `MKMapView` to display a map with a bunch of `MKPolygon`s on it. It can at times end up drawing 1000+ `MKPolygon`s and is starting to affect performance.

Is there a way to draw the polygons on the map more efficiently? Can I draw them all in a single overlay?